# KeyError: 'ENV' when using python to read os environment

Tags: python

I export os environment variable in Fedora 32 like this:

```
export ENV=PRO
```

then I read the env in Python 3.9 like this:

```
import os

current_env = os.environ["ENV"]
```

but throw error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/pydolphin/dolphin/biz/RssEntry.py", line 3, in <module>
    from dolphin.biz.blog.rss.RssAggregator import RssAggregator
  File "/home/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/pydolphin/dolphin/biz/blog/rss/RssAggregator.py", line 2, in <module>
    from dolphin.biz.blog.rss.cnblogs.AtomRssParser import AtomRssParser
  File "/home/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/pydolphin/dolphin/biz/blog/rss/cnblogs/AtomRssParser.py", line 6, in <module>
    from dolphin.biz.blog.rss.RssParser import RssParser
  File "/home/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/pydolphin/dolphin/biz/blog/rss/RssParser.py", line 13, in <module>
    from dolphin.common.Parser import Parser, save_single
  File "/home/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/pydolphin/dolphin/common/Parser.py", line 2, in <module>
    from dolphin.common.db.Article import Article
  File "/home/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/pydolphin/dolphin/common/db/Article.py", line 7, in <module>
    from dolphin.common.db.DatabaseService import Base, session_scope
  File "/home/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/pydolphin/dolphin/common/db/DatabaseService.py", line 8, in <module>
    from dolphin.config.ConfigHelper import ConfigHelper
  File "/home/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/pydolphin/dolphin/config/ConfigHelper.py", line 6, in <module>
    current_env = os.environ["ENV"]
  File "/home/dolphin/anaconda3/envs/pydolphin/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'ENV'
python-BaseException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

why could not read the env? what should I do to read the env? I could read the env using `env` command in terminal. I lanuching my app like this:

```
/home/dolphin/anaconda3/envs/pydolphin/bin/python /home/dolphin/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/212.4746.96/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 35293 --file /home/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/pydolphin/schedulespider.py
```

Comment: How are you launching your python script. I have tried a simple example to replicate what you have and it works fine for me

Comment: I launching the python script in PyCharm debbugger@ChrisDoyle I have pasted the command into my question.

Comment: The pycharm run and debug will spawn in their own enviroment. you should edit your run configuration to set the enviroment variable there. You can edit the run/debug configuration and there is a section for enviroment variables. add it in there

Comment: From all the environment variable names in the world you chose a variable called "ENV"? this is variable is used for global environment variables. Please try using a different var name, then tell us what is the result.